# Azure SQL slow inserts & high latency

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am testing my SQL Server db setup, that is Gen 5 with 4 cores and cannot go over 45 inserts per second for a super simple "insert into test select 'a', 'b', 'c'" query. The same app on the local machine inserts around 5k rows per second. I looked at the pooling and with true goes to 5 and false goes to 45. This is still way below what I expect. Anyone has any idea? What could be wrong? I looked at the metrics in Azure and I see that they CPU is used only 3-4% percent, and memory less than <5%
Any idea?
Connection speed is Okay from what I see. I can do on Cosmos DB around 200 inserts per second with the lowest SKU.

Comment: show us your insert code. you are probably hitting your Log I/O limit. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/02/theres-a-bottleneck-in-azure-sql-db-storage-throughput/

Comment: suggest you post your wait stats: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/

Comment: I found what was the issue. It was in one of the libs that I was using, not holding on the connections, and the app was trying to open a new connection for every call. thanks for the quick reply you provided Mitch.

Comment: @user3053247, I don't know what library you are using but connection pooling will allow the app to open/close connections while avoiding the cost of acquiring a physical connection every time a connection is opened. Pooling eliminates the need for managing persistent connections too.

Comment: be great if you could share a reproducible  code example. Probably stop others having this issue.

Comment: @user3053247 I think there may be some inconvenience for you that you couldn't share the example code for us. I just help you post it as answer. This may could provide some ideas/guides for others and can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you!